# Using local MySQL database with PHP & JavaScript on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am attempting to follow this tutorial - https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3

I have a rather fundamental & simplistic question.

Using firefox, I can see this error when I load the html page with the php and javascript built in, as taken from the tutorial above.

```
TypeError: xml is null
```

The MySQL database I have is on my computer and is not hosted on the website in question. So, when I run the php script that exports the xml in the command line, I can see that it functions correctly.

I attempted to add my ip address to the phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php file, such that -

```
<?php
$username="";
$password="";
$database="";
$host="";
?>
```

But this results in a connection error.

What changes do I need to make for this to be able to reference the database on my computer, rather than one on the site?

EDIT
I have verified that the host, database, password and username fields are correct. I am able to run the phpsqlajax_genxml.php file from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If you run MySql on your computer use "localhost" as a server in phpsqlajax_dbinfo.php:

```
$server="localhost";
```

Your MySql DB is probably not set up to listen to your public IP, if you really want to use your IP you can add it to my.cnf, but I would really recommend using localhost:

```
bind-address    = your_ip
```

Comment: Thanks pun. I tried setting the server as localhost as you suggest, but the Firefox console is still saying "TypeError: xml is null"

Comment: The JS console throws a type error because the PHP script doesn't output any xml. Do you find any errors in the PHP logs?

Comment: Did you test if the query "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1" actually returns something (assuming you use the same code than in the link you provided)?

Comment: that fails, it would appear I simply cannot connect to the MySQL DB. The error lies here. how does my web page know to connect to the localhost of my local computer, when I say $server="localhost"; ?

Comment: Can you add your code to your question? I don't know where you're using the $server variable. The code in your link prints something when connection fails.

Comment: Can you connect from your local computer using mysql-client: mysql -u username -p -h your_server_ip

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73772/discussion-between-learningslowly-and-punkonsole).